# Linux cups how to change printer profile

Tags: cups

Am wondering how can we change printer media size to specific another one from terminal. I checked `lp` and `lpoptions` documentation but not found any specific flag regarding media size set. I have created Media size by name `myLabel_size` so was wondering if can select it from cli so that i can then add it to my script.

i tried but this command do nothing get stuck

`lp -o media=myLabel_size`

[image]

Comment: Try listing what options your printer ppd provides with `lpoptions -l`. (add `-p` and the name of the printer if it is not the default printer).

Comment: @meuh thanks i checked ya it offer media size option `PageSize/Media Size: 17x54 17x87 23x23 29x42 29x90 38x90 39x48 52x29 60x86 62x29 62x100 12Dia 24Dia 58Dia 12X1 29X1 38X1 50X1 54X1 62X1 12X2 29X2 38X2 50X2 54X2 62X2 12X3 29X3 38X3 50X3 54X3 62X3 12X4 29X4 38X4 50X4 54X4 62X4 BrL0B1D03C873FF *BrL081D023DEDDA BrL081D03C34721`
so i tried changing it with different combination's like `lp -o "PageSize/Media Size"=myLabel_size ` , `lp -o "PageSize"=myLabel_size` and `lp -o "Media Size"=myLabel_size`  but the command not execute fully and instead it went for print with stdin

Comment: You can choose one of the preset options with `lpoptions -o PageSize=17x54` for example. If you do this as root it becomes a global setting, but a user can use the same command to set their own choice. I don't know how you can use your own media name. I don't know how the `media` option described by `man lp` interacts with the ppd option `PageSize/Media Size`.

Comment: @meuh i will dig in source code of system-config-printer app to see if can find some clues that how on backend they doing it

Comment: From your issue, I see that option `BrL081D03C34721` is shown as selected (it is prefixed by `*`) after you use the gui to select `myLabel_size`. So perhaps you can simply use `lpoptions -o PageSize=BrL081D03C34721` from the command line to change to this size at any time.

Comment: @meuh thanks for the help i solved the mystery finally lol, the lpoptions changes are only visible on terminal and it not reflect on the GUI printer options. so when we have GUI desktop environment installed then OS also prefer settings of the GUI printer app. so after digging solution was 'lpadmin`  executing  it like `sudo lpadmin -p QL-710W -o PageSize=BrL081D03C34721`  reflect the changes on the GUI printer app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO change printer profile use `lpadmin` instead of `lpoptions` in situation where you have linux distribution with GUI installed.

```bash
sudo lpadmin -p printer_name -o PageSize=my_custom_size

sudo lpadmin -p QL-780W -o PageSize=BrL0B1D03C873FF
```